# How Apache reports errors?

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-server-2008

I have a problem with Apache returning `500 Internal Server Error` on some requests. I thought that when something wrong happens server side, Apache stores the error log in `error.log` file, but I notice that I was wrong: this file contains only the events about when Apache started and stopped (and, I imagine, the errors encountered on server startup).

Event Viewer doesn't display anything neither.

So does Apache at least log errors? If yes, where? If no, are there any third party applications which can track such errors?

---

Context: I'm using Apache 2.2 on Windows Server 2008, trying to setup a SVN server. Any request to the server when SVN is active results in a `500 Internal Server Error` response. I don't know too much about Apache, so please answer in a way understandable by a non-advanced user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Virtual Hosts, it may be that you have opted to have the logs stored as a different name. Generally the convention is to keep all logs in the same folder (or copy them to a user specific folder), and name them something like sitename.com.error.log.

Check your Apache virtual hosts configuration and try to find where they are stored. If you are still stuck, you could potentially use Process Monitor to determine what files are being accessed while your server is running:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: +1 for Process Monitor, I didn't thought myself about using it. But it shows only that Apache is writing to `access.log`, but there is no trace of error files read/write operations. Also, I checked again all the configuration files; there are no virtual hosts and the only two references to `*.log` files are `ErrorLog "logs/error.log"` and `CustomLog "logs/access.log" common`.

Comment: It would appear that there is probably a more significant issue with your Apache installation if it is failing to log errors properly. Perhaps a re-installation of Apache may help, or maybe consider asking in ServerFault, maybe in the chat area to determine whether the question will be strictly on-topic.